Galois Extension of $x^5-5x+12=0$
Jörg Bewersdorff mentions this equation in his book Galois Theory for Beginners: A Historical Perspective (p. 113), saying that its Galois group has order 10. He gives its roots:
\begin{align*}
x_j &= \epsilon^j \sqrt[5]{-1+\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}-3\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} -\frac{11\sqrt{5}}{125}}} \;+ \; \epsilon^{2j} \sqrt[5]{-1-\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}+3\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} +\frac{11\sqrt{5}}{125}}}\\[0.7em]
&+ \epsilon^{3j} \sqrt[5]{-1-\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}-3\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} +\frac{11\sqrt{5}}{125}}} \;+ \; \epsilon^{4j} \sqrt[5]{-1+\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}+3\sqrt{\frac{1}{5} -\frac{11\sqrt{5}}{125}}},\\
\end{align*}
where $\epsilon = \cos{(2\pi/5)} + i \sin{(2\pi/5)}$ and $j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. I'm trying to understand this in terms of the adjunction of field elements. Adjoining the $\{\epsilon_j\}$ extends the field by a factor of five, that's clear. That gives you $\sqrt{5}$, then a quadratic extension brings in $\sqrt{1/5 \pm 11\sqrt{5}/125}$. What I'm not seeing is how you get those four fifth roots.

If you looked back at page 83, the author presented an old method to solve for the root of $x^5+5cx+d$. The rough idea is that he assumed the root $x_j$ has the form $$x_{j+1} =-(\epsilon^jm + \epsilon^{2j}n+\epsilon^{3j}p + \epsilon ^{4j}q)$$
where $j \in \left\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\right\rbrace$ and $\epsilon = e^{2i\pi/5}$. So the goal is to solve for $m,n,p,q$. He then denoted
\begin{align} &y = pq = -mn \\
&r =m^2q+n^2p = -(mp^2+nq^2) \\
& v = m^3p+n^3q \\
& w = mq^3+np^3\end{align}
And derived the following relations
\begin{align}
&dy= (25y^2-c)r\\
&v+w = 3y^2-c \\
&v-w = -r^2/y\\
&rv =(m^5+n^5)y -ry^2\\
&rw = (p^5+q^5)y -ry^2
\end{align}
Using these relations, you can solve for $m,n,p,q$ in term of $r,y,v,w$ as follows:
\begin{align}
&y = \sqrt{z}/5\\
&r = \dfrac{dy}{25y^2-c}\\
&v = \frac{3y^3-cy-r^2}{2y}\\
&w=\frac{3y^3-cy+r^2}{2y}\\
&m,n = \sqrt[5]{\dfrac{v+y^2}{2y}r \pm\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{v+y^2}{2y}r\right)^2+y^5}}
&p,q = \sqrt[5]{\dfrac{w+y^2}{2y}r \pm\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{w+y^2}{2y}r\right)^2-y^5}}
\end{align}
where $z$ is a root of the sextic equation
$$(z-c)^4(z^2-6cz+25c^2) = d^4z$$
Note that the last two expressions of $m,n$ are derived by using Viete's formular for monic quadratic with coefficients $m^5+n^5$ and $(mn)^5$.
So you can see, once we know $z$ (given we can compute it in radical forms), we will know everything. In your particular case, $z$ is a root of the equation $$(z+1)^4(z^2+6z+25)= 20736z.$$ Now I must admit that I have no idea how he solved this, but based on the context, the author pointed out that we just want to solved for some very special quintic equations. So I assumed he just tried and found that $z=5$ is a root, and choosing $y = -\sqrt{5}/5$ yields the desired expression in your post. Here I omitted a lot of steps, just keep the necessary equations to show what is going on. You can unravel the details following the book from page 83-86.
A side note is that, although the roots are expressed in term of $\epsilon$ and some radicals, it doesn't mean the extension field contains $\epsilon$, so you can't say adding $\epsilon$ extend the field by factor of $5$. In fact, since the minimal polynomial of $\epsilon$ is of degree $4$, it only extends by a factor of $4$. I believe the author just claimed that the Galois group of this polynomial has order $10$, without proving it rigorously (or at least I didn't see it). So you can look for a detailed computation here: https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/185.pdf

"Now I must admit that I have no idea how he solved this." He didn't, really. He just fished for a rational root. This is fairly obviously an integer dividing $25$, and also positive as the left side is positive for all real $z$. So it would take few trials to get a hit, if there were one.

This is a standard approach to seeking solutions of quintic equations by radicals. You develop a sextic ewuation whise roots givern what would appear in the raficals, but the sextic equation has a root that can itself be retrieved analytically only if this root is rational. Radical- based firmulas exist fir quintic roots if we have such a resolvent root along with the coefficients of the original equation.

@OscarLanzi Thank you for the insight. I also guessed that he just made some trials and came up with the root $z=5$, but I am no expert to claim that confidently.

Is this method can be extendable ?

@OscarLanzi If in a family of quintics some are reducible, then the sextic resolvent for those may be irreducible as in my answer. (Though, of course, the sextic will still be solvable in radicals.)

Usually whrn we talk abiit "solvable" quintics irrreducibility is understood, in whichs case the radical solutions require a rational root of the sextic. The method of resolvent sextics is meant for irreducible quintics.

Just because you have an expression for $x$ involving $\epsilon$ doesn't mean that you can rearrange it to have $\epsilon,$ i.e. that it's actually in your field. For example $1=1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2},$ but $\sqrt{2}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q.}$
I didn't actually check that the Galois group has order $10,$ but if it does then it can't contain $\epsilon,$ because that extension has degree $4$ and $4$ doesn't divide $10.$

(A long comment.)
I. Monster group
There is more to the solvable quintic $x^5-5x+12=0\,$ than meets the eye, as there is an interesting connection between equations with solvable Galois groups to the sporadic groups. The link between the j-function $j_1(\tau)$ and the Monster is well-known. However, it has a younger brother $j_2(\tau)$ which in turn is connected to the Baby Monster. Given the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$ then,
\begin{align}
j_2(\tau) &=\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{12}+2^6 \left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{12}\right)^2\\[5pt]
&=\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau/2)\,\eta(4\tau)}\right)^{4}-4 \left(\frac{\eta(\tau/2)\,\eta(4\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{4}\right)^4
\end{align}
Ramanujan found most of the integer values of $j_2(\tau)$ in his 1917 paper about $1/\pi$ formulas. For example, $j\big(\tfrac12\sqrt{-10}\big)=12^4$ and $j\big(\tfrac12\sqrt{-58}\big)=396^4$, hence,
\begin{align}
\frac1{\pi} &=32\sqrt2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(4n)!}{n!^4}\frac{10n+1\,}{\;(\color{blue}{12^4})^{n+1/2}}\\[5pt]
\frac1{\pi} &=32\sqrt2\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(4n)!}{n!^4}\frac{\; 58(455n+19)+1}{\;(\color{blue}{396^4})^{n+1/2}}
\end{align}
and we have the solvable quintics,
\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{ x^5-5x+12=0}\\
& x^5-5x+396=0
\end{align}
The first one should be familiar, while the second factors into a quadratic-cubic. To restore the $4$th powers, equivalently,
\begin{align}
& y(y-5)^4=\color{blue}{12^4}\\
& y(y-5)^4=\color{blue}{396^4}
\end{align}
since $j_2(\tau)$ may be negative. For example, Ramanujan also found $j_2\big(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-5}}2\big)=-\big(4\sqrt{2}\big)^4,\,$ $j_2\big(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-13}}2\big)=-\big(12\sqrt{2}\big)^4,\,$ and
$j_2\big(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-37}}2\big)=-\big(84\sqrt{2}\big)^4\,$ hence,
\begin{align}
& y(y-5)^4=-\big(4\sqrt{2}\big)^4\\
& y(y-5)^4=-\big(12\sqrt{2}\big)^4\\
& y(y-5)^4=-\big(84\sqrt{2}\big)^4
\end{align}
are also solvable. In general, suppressing $\tau$ for brevity, we have the solvable quintic,
\begin{align}
x^5-5x\, &= j_2^{1/4}\\[4pt]
y(y-5)^4 &=j_2
\end{align}

II. Resolvent sextic
As pointed out in Tri's answer, the author's resolvent for the quintic $x^5+5cx+d=0\,$ for the case $c=-1$ is given by,
$$d^4=\frac{(z+1)^4(z^2+6z+25)}z$$
Fourth powers again. So in our notation,
$$j_2=\frac{(z+1)^4(z^2+6z+25)}z$$
This is exactly the same sextic found by Joachim König in this 2023 MO post. Thus, if the given quintic is solvable, then so is the sextic. For example, substituting $j_2 = d^4 = 12^4$ into the resolvent, then it factors with $z=5$. However, it does not with $j_2 = d^4 = 396^4$. But since we know,
$$x^5-5x+396 = (x^2 +2x+11)(x^3-2x^2-7x+36) = 0$$
is obviously solvable, then so should be its irreducible resolvent,
$$396^4=\frac{(z+1)^4(z^2+6z+25)}z$$
(since it is dependent on the roots of former) even though it has no linear factor. Testing it with the online Magma calculator, we find it has order $|G|=12\,$ hence is indeed solvable.
